# Error in data frame undefined columns selected when reordering colum in r

Tags: r

I am trying to re-order column based on output genrated from script and getting error despite that all columns are present:

```
cn3 <- wil_test_SNV[,order(coalesce(match(cn3, names(SNV_a)), match(cn3, names(SNV_b))))]
cn3
#[1] 1 2 7 3 6 4 5
class(cn3)
#[1] "integer"
class(wil_test_SNV)
#[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
wil_test_SNV <- data.frame(wil_test_SNV1) #since example shown at last para is working with data.frame object so I though better to convert it into same type
class(wil_test_SNV)
#"data.frame" 
wil_test_SNV1 <- wil_test_SNV[,c(cn3)]
#Error in `[.data.frame`(wil_test_SNV, , c(cn3)) : undefined columns selected
```

while it is working directly by pasting the output

```
paste(cn3, collapse = ", ")
#"1, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5"
wil_test_SNV1 <- wil_test_SNV[,c(1, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5)]
```

In similar example data, I am not getting any errors.

```
#example without any error
df <- data.frame(2:6, 1:5, rnorm(5), rnorm(5), rnorm(5), rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
colnames(df) <- c("TAG", "GT", "PY", "NC", "UUE", "PPE", "EYFH")
class(df)
#"data.frame" 
#creating example output similar to real output
cn3 <- c("1", "6", "3", "4", "5", "2", "7")
cn3 <- as.integer(cn3)
class(cn3)
#[1] "integer"
df <- df[,c(cn3)]
```

Comment: can you include a sample of your data by `dput(wil_test_SNV)`?

Comment: How many columns does `wil_test_SNV` have? "undefined columns selected" could refer to a non-existing column.

Comment: @OttoKässi Although dim of dput(wil_test_SNV) is [1] 60483   463 but I will post part of it once the system end running script. Thank you

Comment: @OttoKässi Thanks now it's working after converting it into a data frame object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `as.vector`:

```
wil_test_SNV1 <- wil_test_SNV[,as.vector(cn3)]
```

Comment: Not working dear but surprisingly now it's working after converting it into a data frame object. I am accepting your answer. Thanks for your kindful follow-up. :)